# Editable TextBlock, Caret Index Query

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, custom-controls

I am developing a Custom Editable Text Block for my Application.  So when the User clicks on the Control, TextBox swaps in for the User to edit the Text. Everything is fine till now, Now my requirement is I want the caret index of TextBox to exactly where the user had clicked on the TextBlock.

So the user won't feel about the swap from UI Point of View.

What approach would be more appropriate? Considering the above factors?!

I am lost in ideas for this thing.

Comment: Why not just have the TextBox in the first place?

Comment: Don't do this! Use a TextBox and toggle its `IsReadOnly` property.

Comment: There are places where a TextBlock is better suited than a TextBox. And sometimes you want to edit that TextBlock. So its a perfectly valid question. We also use an editable TextBlock in our application and its great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you have a UserControl/Customcontrol with its own Mouse handling support, and a way to tell when to switch the content from TextBlock to TextBox.

In the mousedown event you could store the clicked position, swap to the textbox and in the Loaded event you could use [GetCharacterIndexFromPoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.getcharacterindexfrompoint.aspx) to tell which is the position of the click and set the [CaretIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.caretindex.aspx) to that position. You might have to adjust your margins if you use any.

Comment: Thanks for the Response! Adieu ;-)